# Why was my question deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Database Administrators Stack Exchange post: [What prevents me from using SQL Server Developer edition as production](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241593/what-prevents-me-from-using-sql-server-developer-edition-as-production)

so my question it's pretty normal and there's no other question about it why was this deleted? seems like the answer its just "because I don't like it"

Answer (score 13):

I was one of those who voted to delete the question. I saw it first when it was already on hold, and if I had seen it before, I would probably be one of the close-voters too.

Yes, you could very well say I did not like the question. But it is one thing to dislike something because it is pointless and quite another if it is potentially harmful. Why would I want to know *how* a company discovers I am violating their licensing terms? I do not suggest there can be no justification to such a desire, but with none given whatsoever it is hard not to consider less than honourable motives. Letting someone find out about ways they can be exposed, so that they can be prepared to evade that, is not the kind of help this site has been designed to provide, nor the kind I myself would agree should be out there in the open, even if I generally agreed with the direction Libertheme's response took.

Besides, licensing questions are hardly on topic here. At least, I can see nothing worth elaborating on in this specific case that a professional working with databases would need to know to perform their duties properly.

Comment: I was the origonal close voter, I agree 100% with everything presented in your answer, @Andriy